# Not getting the value of session in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, session

I am engaged in a Django project where I am stuck in a situation that I am unable to get the value of session from one function to another function. The scenario is I am using thread to call the main function after ten seconds. Before using the threading everything was working fine and normal and I was also getting the value of session but by using thread now, I am unable to get the value of sessions:

views.py:

```
def results(request):
  user_id = request.session['user_id']
  

  def thread_check(request, user_id):
    time.sleep(10)
    hash_id, id_exists = compliance(user_id)
    request.session['hash_id'] = hash_id
    request.session.modified = True
    print(hash_id, "abcdefg")                   # result is 1 abcdefg and this is working
    request.session['id_exists'] = id_exists

  threads = threading.Thread(target=thread_check, args=(request, user_id))
  threads.start()
  # time.sleep(7)
  request.session['check_status'] = False
  id_exists = request.session.get('id_exists')
  if id_exists:
    messages.success(request, "This File has already been analyzed")

 
  return redirect(process)

def process(request, stat=None):
  
  hash_id = request.session.get('hash_id')
  request.session.modified = True
  print(hash_id, "hash id")         #result is None hash id
  check = request.session.pop('check_status', True)
  if hash_id and check:
    stat = status_mod.objects.filter(hash_id = hash_id).order_by('-id').first()
    if stat:
      stat = stat.stat_id
    print(stat, "status id ")
    
  return render(request, 'enroll/status.html', {'status': stat})
```

I dont know where is the mistake, Why am I not getting the value of session.

Comment: Can't you pass the request for results on to the function process?
With that said, I will recommend you set up a SessionStore for your project.
Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/)

Comment: can u elaborate more.?? @enslaved_programmer

Comment: Can you provide me with how your session backend is configured?
That said, it is a good practice to keep a web application stateless.
Regarding you setting the session in a different thread, there is no guarantee that the next accessing request is accessing with the same thread that set the value.

Comment: I have used SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True in settings.py and 'django.contrib.sessions', in installed apps and middleware sessions which are already included in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a separate thread to set the value of hash_id in the session. Instead, you can set the value directly in the results view function before redirecting to the process view function.

Comment: hash_id, id_exists = compliance(user_id), this line is used to run the external python script and I am getting the hash_id from that python script and it is mandatory to run python script after 10 sec of page rendering. so it cannot be out of threading